# react-query useMutation initialisation fails on second page visit

Tags: reactjs, react-query

This is my mutation definition

```
const deletePolicyMutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: ({ policyId }) => deletePolicyDetails(policyId),
    onSuccess: () => {
      resetParametersAndFetchData();
      showToast("Policy Deleted", TOAST_TYPES.SUCCESS);
      closeModal();
    },
    onError: (e) => {
      console.error(e);
      showToast(
        "An error occurred while deleting the policy. Please try again later.",
        TOAST_TYPES.DANGER
      );
    },
  });
```

and this is the error:
[image]

What's more puzzling is that this doesn't happen in local. Only in builds